# Point exteral domain to subdomain while keeping domain intact

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, redirect, subdomain, vhosts

My app uses subdomains to create different pages for my users.

For example:

```
user1.coredomain.com -> User1's index
user1.coredomain.com/profile -> User1's personal profile
...
```

Now a user want's to use their own domain and want to point it to my subdomain:

```
user1domain.bz-> user1.coredomain.com -> User1's index
user1domain.bz/profile -> user1.coredomain.com/profile -> User1's profile
...
```

He's domain is to be intact and always shown in the browser.

I'm using subdomain wildcards to create the subdomains for my users. Build in Laravel 5.

I'm quite out of my league here and not even sure where to begin. Google didn't help much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so If I get this right you have setup Laravel routes to use wildcard subdomains as the user's username. ie

```
dave.appname.com
john.appname.com
```

If this is correct you would the the user to create a Cname Record and point it your domain.

```
ie cname john.com to john.appname.com
```

So when they visit john.com its serving your john.appname.com

Does this make sense !